# Change database for db:seed - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, database, laravel-5.1

I've seen how to set the database in the query, the migration and controller ... Now I need a seed for the secondary tables, but do not know how to define it. I tried as follows:

```
App\Client::connection('mysql2')->create(['email' => 'adm@test.com', ..
```

but not work.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: [BadMethodCallException]
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::connection()

Comment: Have you tried using `php artisan db:seed --database=AConnectionName` ? Why do you need to specify into the seeder?

Comment: I tried not specify this way.I must give the seed of the two databases that have, and thus will only 1. How can I specify the seed file and database in charge db: seed?